# 非切片精分，1V1，丧了吧唧强大攻 mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

非切片精分，1V1，丧了吧唧强大攻 I read it in some web novel's description. What does it mean? I know about 1v1 and gong. Please help me understand the rest. Thank you.

Comment: Can you add more context or source?

Answer (score 2):

That's a bunch of 耽美 (danmei, Chinese equivalent to yaoi) jargon. I consulted a 腐女 friend and here's what I learned.

As @zsLiu's answer says, these are all tags describing the exact setting and subgenre of the novel, but the descriptions could be more precise.

- 非切片精分：非 means "not". 精分 is short for 精神分裂, which is the medical term for schizophrenia. However, it is commonly misunderstood to mean multiple personalities (likely through a literal reading of 精神分裂, "mental splitting"), and this is the meaning adopted in the danmei community. 切片精分, where 切片 literally means "slicing", refers to a specific setting where a character not only has multiple personalities, but those personalities occupy separate bodies.
- 1v1: mutually exclusive relationship
- 丧了吧唧: 丧 literally means "to mourn" or "to lose". In recent years it gained a specific meaning of "losing interest in life", or decadent. 了吧唧 is an informal intensifier.
- 强大: this is the easiest one, it means "strong". The reason it is here is probably to contrast with 丧, since a decadent character is more likely to be weak.
- 攻: top

There is some ambiguity around 非切片精分: It can be read as either 非(切片精分) or (非切片)精分. It is also not clear whether 非切片精分 refers to the plot in general, or the top specifically.

So overall this soup of danmei tags can be translated as the following:

- No multiple personalities in separate bodies plot

  - Or, multiple personalities plot without separate bodies
  - Or, the top doesn't have multiple personalities in separate bodies
  - Or, the top has multiple personalities but not separate bodies
- Mutually exclusive relationship
- Decadent but strong top

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you are reading some *strange* (usually erotic & ideal) novels. If you are learning Chinese, reading these won't be helpful.

In 「非切片精分，1V1，丧了吧唧强大攻」, 「非切片精分，1V1，丧了吧唧强大」are (at least) four adjectives which describe 「攻」。

- 「攻」: you have already known the meaning
- 「非切片精分」: has a stable
  mental state
- 「1V1」: you have already known the meaning
- 「丧了吧唧」: has a depressing attitude towards his/her life
- 「强大」: has a strong body/ability, etc